# jQuery - use .find() and .html() multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to use the jQuery feature .find() and .html() on the same parent object. Like this:

```
$('.confirm-booking')
 .find('.config_shipper_label')
 .html(formConfig.shipper_labels === 1 ? 'Yes' : 'No')
 .find('.config_batteri')
 .html(formConfig.batteri_labels === 1 ? 'Yes' : 'No');
```

However, apparently, it stops after the first `.html()` function.

So my `.config_shipper_label` element have the correct value (either Yes or No), however, my `.config_batteri` element is just empty.

I have a lot more elements, that I need to go through, so how can I achieve above scenario the best way?

Comment: You need to add `.end()` after `.html()` so it will go back up the stack (Back to `$('.confirm-booking')`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that they have the same logic as the example, extract it to a function:

```js
var formConfig = {
  shipper_labels: 1,
  batteri_labels: 0
}

var doStuff = function(element, setting) {
  $('.confirm-booking')
    .find(element)
    .html(setting === 1 ? 'Yes' : 'No');
}

doStuff('.config_shipper_label', formConfig.shipper_labels);
doStuff('.config_batteri', formConfig.batteri_labels);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="confirm-booking">
  <div class="config_shipper_label">
  </div>
  <div class="config_batteri">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot chain it like the way you did. You must use jQuery's [end](https://api.jquery.com/end/) method like so:

```
$('.confirm-booking')
    .find('.config_shipper_label')
    .html(formConfig.shipper_labels === 1 ? 'Yes' : 'No')
    .end()
    .find('.config_batteri')
    .html(formConfig.batteri_labels === 1 ? 'Yes' : 'No');
```